# ILMerge / ILRepack dlls fail to register with Dynamics 365 plugin registration tool

Tags: .net, dll, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, ilmerge

I'm trying to create a plugin for D365.  I have package dependencies including

- Azure.DigitalTwins.Core
- Azure.Core
- Azure.Identity

These .dll dependencies must be merged into a single .dll to register a plugin.  I'm using an [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge#to-run-ilmerge-in-a-batch-file) batch file script to combine these dlls into a single `merged.dll` output.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
@echo off
:: this script needs https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge

:: Set build, used for directory. Typically Release or Debug
SET ILMERGE_BUILD=bin\Debug\ilmerge

:: set your NuGet ILMerge Version, this is the number from the package manager install, for example:
:: PM> Install-Package ilmerge -Version 3.0.29
:: to confirm it is installed for a given project, see the packages.config file
SET ILMERGE_VERSION=3.0.41

:: the full ILMerge should be found here:
SET ILMERGE_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\ilmerge\%ILMERGE_VERSION%\tools\net452
:: dir "%ILMERGE_PATH%"\ILMerge.exe

SET PROJECT_ROOT=%CD%
SET ASSEMBLY_DIR=%PROJECT_ROOT%\bin\Debug\net462

::/targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0" ^
::/target:library ^
::/copyattrs ^
::/closed ^
::/allowDup ^

echo Merging adtplugin...
:: add project DLL's starting with replacing the FirstLib with this project's DLL
"%ILMERGE_PATH%"\ILMerge.exe ^
/keyfile:%PROJECT_ROOT%\adtplugin.snk ^
/out:%ILMERGE_BUILD%\merged.dll ^
/target:library ^
/nDebug ^
/closed ^
/allowDup ^
/copyattrs ^
/targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2" ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\adtplugin.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Azure.Core.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Azure.DigitalTwins.Core.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Azure.Identity.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\netstandard.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\System.Memory.dll ^
%ASSEMBLY_DIR%\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll 

pause
:Done
```

I've played around quite a bit with the /option flags passed to ILMerge.exe. Currently with the config shown, I'm able to merge the .dlls listed into a single merged.dll output.

Next, I'm trying to use the Plug-in registration tool to register a new assembly using the `merged.dll` output file.  When I try to register the plugin I'm getting errors:

[image: Plug-in registration tool]

Here's the error dump:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unable to load plug-in assembly.
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActivityId>9e6ed737-8374-464e-956a-d70b46a2c686</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147204719</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiExceptionSourceKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Plugin/Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.PluginAssemblyService</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiSourceActivityKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineStep</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiExceptionOwnerKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">COMMONDATASERVICECDS\CDSAPI-Reliability</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiOriginalExceptionKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Unable to load plug-in assembly. ---&gt; Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Unable to load plug-in assembly.
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.PluginAssemblyServiceInternal`1.LoadCrmPluginAssemblyMetadata(IBusinessEntity pluginAssembly, IExecutionContext context, Boolean loadAllMetadata)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.PluginAssemblyServiceInternal`1.RetrieveAssemblyMetadata(IBusinessEntity pluginAssembly, ExecutionContext context, Boolean retrieveFromExisting, Boolean forSystemAssembly)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.PluginAssemblyServiceInternal`1.ValidateOperation(String operationName, IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SdkEntityServiceBase.CreateInternal(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context, Boolean verifyAction)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName, ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7_0.&lt;RunStep&gt;b__0()</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiStepKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:guid" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">3ecabb1b-ea3e-db11-86a7-000a3a5473e8</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiDepthKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">1</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiActivityIdKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:guid" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">9e6ed737-8374-464e-956a-d70b46a2c686</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiPluginSolutionNameKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">System</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiStepSolutionNameKey</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">System</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiExceptionCategory</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">SystemFailure</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiExceptionMessageName</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">UnableToLoadPluginAssembly</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>ApiExceptionHttpStatusCode</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:int" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">500</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>0</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Failed to load plugin assembly with exception Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: GetAssemblyMetadata: expected mdtAssemblyRef or mdtAssembly
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmException.Assert(Boolean condition, String message)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.GetAssemblyMetadata(UInt32 token)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessTypeRef(UInt32 typeRef)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessType(UInt32 token)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessTypeDef(UInt32 typeDef)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessType(UInt32 token)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.LoadMetadata()
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.LoadMetadataFromAssemblyContent(ArraySegment`1 assemblyContents, Boolean loadAllMetadata)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.LoadMetadataFromAssemblyContent(String content, Boolean loadAllMetadata)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.PluginAssemblyServiceInternal`1.LoadCrmPluginAssemblyMetadata(IBusinessEntity pluginAssembly, IExecutionContext context, Boolean loadAllMetadata). PluginInfo =&gt; Crm plugin assembly info : sourcetype = 0, description = , ismanaged = False, pluginassemblyid = b77380cb-8676-45b6-9e5c-63a5960ed2ac, ispasswordset = False, publickeytoken = 7F66FA42F6885FDC, name = merged, culture = neutral, isolationmode = 2, version = 1.0.0.0, </a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>1</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: GetAssemblyMetadata: expected mdtAssemblyRef or mdtAssembly
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmException.Assert(Boolean condition, String message)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.GetAssemblyMetadata(UInt32 token)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessTypeRef(UInt32 typeRef)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessType(UInt32 token)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessTypeDef(UInt32 typeDef)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.ProcessType(UInt32 token)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.LoadMetadata()
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.LoadMetadataFromAssemblyContent(ArraySegment`1 assemblyContents, Boolean loadAllMetadata)
   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmPluginAssemblyMetadata.LoadMetadataFromAssemblyContent(String content, Boolean loadAllMetadata)
   at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.PluginAssemblyServiceInternal`1.LoadCrmPluginAssemblyMetadata(IBusinessEntity pluginAssembly, IExecutionContext context, Boolean loadAllMetadata)</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <HelpLink>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398563&amp;error=Microsoft.Crm.CrmException%3a80044191&amp;client=platform</HelpLink>
  <Message>Unable to load plug-in assembly.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2021-04-29T17:46:08.9958593Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault>
    <ActivityId>9e6ed737-8374-464e-956a-d70b46a2c686</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147204719</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <HelpLink i:nil="true" />
    <Message>Unable to load plug-in assembly.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2021-04-29T17:46:08.9958593Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.RegistrationHelper.RegisterAssembly(CrmOrganization org, String pathToAssembly, CrmPluginAssembly assembly) in D:\a\1\s\src\GeneralTools\PluginRegistrationV3\PluginRegistration\CrmLibraries\RegistrationHelper.cs:line 723
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.AssemblyRegistration.PluginRegistrationViewModel.RegisterAssembly() in D:\a\1\s\src\GeneralTools\PluginRegistrationV3\RegistrationTools\AssemblyRegistration\ViewModels\PluginRegistrationViewModel.cs:line 649
```

If anyone has had success using a .bat script to run ILMerge, merging .dll files, and using the output to register a D365 Plugin, please let me know!  (extremely specific... I know haha)

### Update

I've now switched to ILRepack and ILRepack.Lib.MSBuild.Task.  I'm using the following config in a ILRepack.targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="ILRepacker" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
      <!--<InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)\*.dll" />-->
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)adtplugin.dll" />
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Azure.Core.dll" />
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Azure.DigitalTwins.Core.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Azure.Identity.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)System.Memory.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"/>
      <!--<InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll"/>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)netstandard.dll"/>-->
      
    </ItemGroup>

    <ILRepack
        Parallel="true"
        Internalize="false"
        InternalizeExclude="@(DoNotInternalizeAssemblies)"
        InputAssemblies="@(InputAssemblies)"
        LibraryPath="$(OutputPath)"
        Wildcards="false"
        TargetKind="SameAsPrimaryAssembly"
        DebugInfo="false"
        KeyFile="adtplugin.snk"
        OutputFile="$(OutputPath)Merged\$(AssemblyName).dll"
        LogFile="$(OutputPath)Merged\ILRepack.log"
    />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The merge succeeds, but the plugin registration is still failing with the same error dump shown above.

Comment: My advice: stop using ILMerge. Instead use ILRepack, it is now easy to add to your project. See [this article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815639/crm-using-ilmerge-to-merge-framework-library-with-plugin-projects/66816173#66816173).

Comment: I switched over the ILRepack (and updated my question info), but I'm still getting the same plugin registration error : /

Comment: Are you merging .NET Core assemblies? Assemblies must be based on .NET Framework 4 and cannot be from the System namespace.

Comment: Looking at your assemblies I think an option could be creating an Azure component (e.g. web API) and call it from your plugin using a plain HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to avoid merging anything that's part of the .NET Framework (which I assume that libraries like `System.Memory` and `System.Threading.Tasks` are).

That being said, based on the DLLs you're merging, even if you get it to register, depending on what the code actually does, the limitations of the [sandbox environment](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/understanding-plugin-sandbox-mode/) may prevent the plugin from running.

If that turns out to be the case, you might want to look into an [Azure Aware Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/write-custom-azure-aware-plugin) instead.

I once had a plugin where I had to do RSA signature verification. I tried using the .NET libraries but the sandbox prohibited the RSA-related code from running. I wound up having to "roll my own" using an open source RSA library I found called EZ-RSA.

Thanks for the update. I looked into the error message a little more. I found [this article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nishantranaweblog/posts/microsoft-crm-crmexception-getassemblymetadata-expected-mdtassemblyref-or-mdtassembly-while-registering-plugin-assembly-in-dynamics-365) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959902/dynamics-crm-2016-on-prem-plugin-exception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-m) where the developer seems to conclude that ILMerging an Identity library is a showstopper.

As far as the merge/repack path goes, you might want to use a blank project and merge the DLLs one-by-one, testing the plugin registration after each one to see which library or libraries break the registration.

The last I heard, even when it works, ILMerge is technically unsupported. What is supported is an Azure Aware Plugin.

You can register your plugin to to call out to a service endpoint or webhook when it fires:
[image: reg1]

For the Service Endpoint it can hit various types of listeners in an Azure Service Bus Queue (via a connection string or this configuration dialog).
[image: service endpoint]

And calling out to a Webhook is also an option:
[image: webhook]

Comment: Strangely, when I don't explicitly include `System.Memory` and `System.Threading.Tasks`, the plugin registration fails with an error saying those packages could not be found.  That's why they are on this list, but I agree.  Those shouldn't need to be included, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I've switched over to ILRepack and updated my question, but the plugin registration is still failing with the same error dump.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I enhanced my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Fody** package to merge your .dll-s after build action. First, you need to install [Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/) and [Costura.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody) via nuget. It will add some references and the file *FodyWeavers.xml* which you can fill this way

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Costura />
</Weavers>
```

Then in the *Solution Explorer* select the references for the assemblies which you want to merge together and in the *Properties Window* change ***Copy Local*** to ***True***. For those assemblies you don't want to include in the merge process select ***Copy Local*** - ***False***

Rebuild your solution and in the output you'll got merged dll.