# MethodAccessException: Attempt by method X to access method Y failed in Dynamics 365 Plugin On Prem

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, methodaccessexception

I'm getting the error below when trying to move a plugin from version .NET version 4.5.2 to 4.6.2 in Dynamics 365 v9.1

```
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'System.Net.Http.WinHttpResponseParser.GetReasonPhrase(System.Net.HttpStatusCode, Char[], Int32)' to access method 'System.Net.HttpStatusDescription.Get(System.Net.HttpStatusCode)' failed.
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpResponseParser.GetReasonPhrase(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Char[] buffer, Int32 bufferLength)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpResponseParser.CreateResponseMessage(WinHttpRequestState state, Boolean doManualDecompressionCheck)
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__103.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
```

I can deploy the plugin and it works fine. I'm getting the error above when the plugin attempts to make a web service call to an external API we call from the plugin

The plugin is NOT in sandbox mode and it's registered in the database
[image]

I opened the plugin assembly with JustDecompile and tracked down the issue to loading a method in System.dll, it looks  like it's trying to load it from the GAC and fails.

[image]

Anyone had the same issue? This same plugin works in .NET 4.5.2 but fails in 4.6.2

Comment: Does this issue occur on a particular machine? Did you check the platform target of your assembly (Any CPU/x86/c64). On that machine does your component work when executed from a console app e.g.?

Comment: target framework is 4.6.2. I’ve got other orgs running plugins in 4.6.2 in the same machine with no problem. The only issue seems to be this particular plug-in that makes an external API call, it works if target is 4.5.2 but it fails in 4.6.2. I haven’t tried running it in a console app, We do have other web services in the same machine using 4.6.2 that make use of System.Net.Http

Comment: Did you check the platform target of your assembly (Any CPU/x86/x64)?

Comment: target framework is 4.6.2 and any CPU. In any case, the issue was that we were including the System.*.dll, added an answer with the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to find a solution for this, the problem was ILMerge was including all System.*.dll, reading in this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334636/2059998

> You might want to avoid merging anything that's part of the .NET Framework (which I assume that libraries like System.Memory and System.Threading.Tasks are).

So adding the line `<Files Remove="$(TargetDir)System*.dll" />` for ILMerge in the .NET project file fixed the issue, this makes sure the files are not included when running ILMerge

```xml
<Target Name="ILMerge" AfterTargets="Build">
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="$(TargetDir)*.dll" />
    <Files Remove="$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).dll" /> 
    <Files Remove="$(TargetDir)AntiXSSLibrary.dll" />
    <Files Remove="$(TargetDir)Microsoft*.dll" />
    <Files Remove="$(TargetDir)System*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```